# Basic Java Initialize concept

Tags: javascript

```
Data (Global Variables):

Car color.
Car x location.
Car y location.
Car x speed.
```

Setup:

```
Initialize car color.
Initialize car location to starting point.
Initialize car speed.
```

Draw:

```
Fill background.
Display car at location with color.
Increment car's location by speed.
```

I read this from a website of basic concepts Initialize.

Why do we need to Initialize?

What does it helps for creating an object?

How we adjust and make the correct initialize for the object we need?

Comment: Java or JavaScript? They are very much different.

Comment: *"Why do we need to Initialize?"* It ensures that the object's properties have valid values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't initialize you wouldn't be able to access the objects property (Because it would be undefined).

```
var test = {
    definedProperty : "Hello"
};

alert(test.definedProperty);
alert(test.undefinedProperty);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3cWzw/

Comment: @Downvoter - would you like to comment?